# AndroidDriver is not being returned

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

The error being shown is :

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchSessionException
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:111)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:73)`

The control is reaching till the print statement before returning the Android Driver.
But the android driver is not returned.
I have checked my appium server is running fine.

```
private static AppiumDriver<WebElement> getdriver_app(Map<String, String> appiumconfig){
    try{
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
    cap.setCapability("deviceName", "HNB1130T");
    cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0");
    cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.tajawal");
    cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.tajawal.main.MainActivity");
    cap.setCapability("noReset", true);
    System.out.println("going to return driver");
    return new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
    }
    catch ( MalformedURLException ex){
        System.out.println("Invalid URL Given in Config Properties");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: A google shows a similar problem with older chromedriver. Can you check your version of chromedriver?

Comment: Hi, Can you please share error logs from Appium server?

Comment: @AnishPillai Appium Server is not giving any logs.

Comment: The problem has been solved.I was having compatibility issues with appium,selenium versions.